# Call a function from the front end using HTMX

Tags: django-views, django-templates, htmx

I have a function in my views that gets data from a JSON file and them formats that data in a way so that it can be rendered to a template.

I want to call that function from the front end without refreshing the page.
Right now I'm looking into using HTMX to achieve this.

Is this doable using HTMX, if so what would be the best way to do so?
If not, what tool / method should I look into using?

https://github.com/LucaBazzea/flashcard-1000/blob/main/core/views.py

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what event should trigger the request. For example if you need some lazy loading you can do this:

```
<div
    hx-get="{% url 'get_index' %}"
    hx-trigger="load"
    hx-swap="innerHTML"
>
</div>
```

You need to remember to use fragmented template for response to only include the necessary html content.